# How to perform integer modular exponentiation in Golang

Tags: go, modular-arithmetic

How to calculate `a**b % m` where all the members are integers, and `a^b` is outside the `int` range?

I.e. to raise `a` to the power `b` under modulo `m`. I.e. an equivalent of this Python code:

```py
pow(a, b, m)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Exp](https://pkg.go.dev/math/big#Int.Exp) function from the built-in [math/big](https://pkg.go.dev/math/big) package. But it requires plenty of type conversions.

```golang
import "math/big"

func pow(a, b, m int) int {
    result := new(big.Int).Exp(
        big.NewInt(int64(a)),
        big.NewInt(int64(b)),
        big.NewInt(int64(m)),
    )
    return int(result.Uint64())
}
```

[Try it](https://go.dev/play/p/a7dJMn6JbE7).

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to do this in a more memory-efficient way, without resorting to big integers.

This is a direct translation from the [pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Memory-efficient_method) found on Wikipedia:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func modPow(a, b, m int) int {
    if m == 1 {
        return 0
    }

    c := 1

    for i := 0; i < b; i++ {
        c = (c * a) % m
    }

    return c
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(modPow(1234, 5678, 9012))
}
```

<sup>**Disclaimer:** I don't know golang :)</sup>

---

[Playground link](https://go.dev/play/p/xfjVoREgV5v)

Comment: This has a limitation: `m` had better be a 32bit integer if `int` is 64bit (otherwise `c * a` could overflow) (this also requires that `a < m` but that's a reasonable limitation). Also looping `b` times is very inefficient, exponentiation by squaring does it in log(b) steps. Having to convert to and from BigInt is a disadvantage but at least that approach avoids these things.

Comment: Here is a manual and efficient calculation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77556267/1118709

Answer (score 0):

Calculating the exponent manually as [suggested by Robby](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77542196/1118709), but efficiently:

```golang
func pow(a, b, m int) int {
    if b < 0 {
        panic("Negative power given")
    }

    result := 1
    power := a

    for b > 0 {
        if b & 1 == 1 {
            result = result * power % m
        }
        power = power * power % m
        b >>= 1
    }

    return result
}
```

This is an iterative version of [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring#With_constant_auxiliary_memory). The time complexity is O(log(b)) if we assume that every multiplication takes O(1) time.

[Try it](https://go.dev/play/p/UtYOkDNWka0).

#### Negative power

If `m` is [prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number), it's possible to calculate the negative power. It requires 2 steps:

1. Calculate the positive power
2. Divide 1 by the result using [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem)

```golang
func powUniversal(a, b, m int) int {
    if b >= 0 {
        return pow(a, b, m)
    }
    subResult := pow(a, -b, m)
    return pow(subResult, m - 2, m)
}
```

You can check that it works by asserting `powUniversal(a, b, m) * powUniversal(a, -b, m) % m == 1`.